# Why did Beethoven use triplets for the whole first movement of Moonlight Sonata rather than writing it in say 6/8?

Tags: time-signatures, tuplet

I just came across the score for Beethoven's Moonlight Sonata, and I was surprised when I saw [the time signature of the first movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_Sonata_No._14_(Beethoven)#I._Adagio_sostenuto).

(My background is that I've played music for many years—mainly guitars and keyboard—but not studied music theory beyond what was covered in piano lessons as a child. So I have a basic understanding of time signatures, note values, triplets and suchlike, and am used to working with them. Although while the C-shaped time signature symbol means 4/4 or Common Time, I did have to search to learn that the vertical line through it means [either tempus imperfectum diminutum or Alla breve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_signature#Simple_vs._compound).)

My surprise came when I saw that the movement is written in 4/4 (or is it 2/2?), with the melody as triplets across it. Without really thinking about it, I had assumed it would be in something like 6/8.

Previously, I've only encountered triplets as occasional exceptions that bring a certain emphasis to short sections by their contrast. Yet here, triplets are the norm for the entire movement. What is going on here?

Comment: Just to confirm your side point, by the way: the time signature of “c with a line through” does indeed mean 2/2.  It’s very commonly used in classical music, and usually known as “cut time”.  “Alla breve” is less common and a bit more acaedmic/formal, at least in my experience.  And only specialists/enthusiasts will have heard of “tempus imperfectum diminutum” — that’s very archaic terminology from mediaeval music, and as far as I know it ’s now used only in the study of such early music.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In piano music (at least) **it fairly common to write in 4/4 time** with all triplets. This most frequently happens **when the melody itself is best expressed in 4/4**, while the accompaniment, in triplets, could otherwise be expressed in 12/8.

#### Examples

**"Moonlight" Sonata"**
This is the case of the "Moonlight" Sonata. While the accompaniment is in triplets throughout, the melody is a "4/4" (actually 2/2) melody. The below image shows the initial entrance of the melody in measured 5-7.

[image: "Moonlight" Sonata mm. 5-7]
([IMAGE SOURCE](https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/d/d0/IMSLP218185-PMLP01458-Beethoven_Op_27_No_2_I.pdf))

Expressing this in 12/8 would be somewhat misleading, in that it would imply the primacy of the triplets as well as being harder to read. (It would also suggest a 4-beat metric accent pattern rather than 2-beat.)

```
X: 1
T: Moonlight Sonata
T: in 12/8 time
M: 12/8
K: C# minor
L: 1/8
%%score (V1 | V2)V:V1
V:V2
[V:V1] z6 z3 (2:3:2G3/2G/2 | G6-G3 (2:3:2G3/2G/2 | G6
[V:V2 stem=down] G,CE G,CE G,CE G,CE | G,DF G,DF G,DF G,DF |
```

**Chopin Nocturne in F Major (Op. 15, No. 1)**

This kind of "12/8 written as 4/4" is characteristic of Chopin's Nocturnes. The accompaniment is often triplet based, but the melodies are 4/4. The following example, from Op. 15, No. 1 in F major, is written in 3/4, though the accompaniment is in 9/8.

[image: Chopin Op. 15 No. 1, mm. 1-4]
([IMAGE SOURCE](https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/c/ca/IMSLP50497-PMLP02311-Chopin_Nocturnes_Schirmer_Mikuli_Op_15.pdf))

**Chopin Noturne in Eb Major (Op. 9, No. 2)**

By contrast, consider Chopin's Nocturne in Eb Major (Op. 9, No. 2). Here, the piece is given in 12/8; but note that in this case, the melody is also triplet based.

[image: Chopin Nocturne in Eb Major, m. 1]
([IMAGE SOURCE](https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/1/14/IMSLP61906-PMLP02312-Chopin-Op09n2rje.pdf))

**Chopin Nocturne in B Major (Op. 9, No. 3)**

A particularly illuminating example comes from Chopin's Nocturne in B major (Op. 9, No. 3), which employs both 6/8 (for the A section) and 2/2 (for the B section).

[image: Chopin Op. 15 No. 3, mm. 1-4]
[image: Chopin Op. 15 No. 3, mm. 88-89]
([IMAGE SOURCE](https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/7/7d/IMSLP50496-PMLP02312-Chopin_Nocturnes_Schirmer_Mikuli_Op_9.pdf))

Comment: I always thought that the bass was the accompaniment and that the triplets were the melody...

Answer (score 10):

If you look further in the score, you will notice sixteenth notes in the melody (dotted rhythm, strictly speaking). Notating or reading this in 6/8 would be much more awkward.

Compare clarity of the rhythm notation in these two measures:

[image]

See some more related discussion:

[How to play this rhythm in Beethoven's Moonlight Sonata? as a 4/3 polyrythm or as 6/16?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/91393/how-to-play-this-rhythm-in-beethovens-moonlight-sonata-as-a-4-3-polyrythm-or-a)

[Piano: quaver triplets in RH v dotted quaver and semiquaver in LH](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/84549/piano-quaver-triplets-in-rh-v-dotted-quaver-and-semiquaver-in-lh)

[Developing Hand independence and Finger independence](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/77764/63781)

[Why is the last semiquaver outside the last triplet of the measure?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6986/why-is-the-last-semiquaver-outside-the-last-triplet-of-the-measure)

Comment: Your notated examples are not equivalent. In 4/4 time, a sixteenth-note is one fourth of a (quarter-note) beat; whereas in 6/8 time, a 32nd-note is 1/12th of a (dotted-quarter-note) beat.

Comment: @Aaron Yes, they are equivalent. A quarter note is 2/3 of the beat, plus 32nd note, which is, as you correctly point, 1/12 of the beat give 2/3 + 1/12 = 8/12 + 1/12 = 9/12 = 3/4 of the beat. Dotted 16th note is 3/12 = 1/4 of the beat. 3/4 + 1/4 corresponds to the proportions of the dotted rhythm from the first measure. Your question demonstrates how inconvenient it would be to use such notation.

Comment: Ah, I see. I missed the dot. Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: @Aaron Not your fault, I made it show how bad it would look like. Maybe with use of duplet notation it would look better, but I think musicians are more used to and trained to read triplet rhythms.